# Is it possible to infer information about the structure of the universe beyond the observable one?

Tags: astrophysics, cosmological-horizon

Is it possible to infer information about the structure of the universe beyond the observable one, by observing its effects on the parts we can see? Can for example gravity from sources we cannot see affect objects which we can see, and allow us to calculate the mass or directions of the source?

Comment: Maybe. ;) As I said [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32458/16685), if the curvature were significantly greater outside our observable patch we'd expect the curvature to be a bit higher near the edges than it is in the middle of the patch, and we don't see that in the data.